# Vector won't store correct datatype (wchar_t instead of uint16_t)

Tags: c++, wchar-t

I have some code from the net reading hyperspectral data (image, so lots of integers giving pixel intensity) into a vector. I used the code with success on a Linux system, but now I need the same on a windows system. I use Visual Studio 2008.

Reading the data in Linux I get a vector full of integers. On windows I get the integers and then some chars or byte data. I don't know enough to describe it better.

The vector is initialized by

```
std::vector< unsigned short int > data;
data.resize( samples * lines * bands );
std::fill( data.begin(), data.end(), 0 );
```

and the relevant code is

```
for( unsigned int i=0; i < num_pixels && file; ++i ){
     char number[sizeof(DataType)];
     file.read( number , sizeof( DataType ) );
     int l = sizeof(DataType)-1;
    if (machine_endian != header.big_endian) {
        for (int j = 0; j < l; j++, l--){
            number[j] ^=number[l];
            number[l] ^= number[j];
            number[j] ^= number[l];
        }
    }
 unsigned short temp = *((unsigned short int*)number);
     data[i] = temp;
}
```

The machine_endian part is never run. The temp is just to test if I can cast the number into an int. It works fine. However, when I put temp into the vector there's more information inserted than just the int and it's listed as wchar_t. See the image below. I guess it's something to do with type size, but I am clueless as to why. Is it mine or Visual Studios fault? Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: `wchar_t` is defined as `unsigned short` (and if it's not directly defined as that, it's two bytes and behaves the same way) so it's just typename display issue. Are the numbers correct (regardless of type)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Ok, that clears up a bit. Unfortuantely I can't check the numbers for certain right now, but I have no reason to believe they are incorrect (reasonable value). If it's very important I can try to get the values, but it's a bit of work. But how can they be saved fine in the temp variable and then get extra data in the vector when it's initialized with the same datatype?

Comment: Sorry, English is not my first language, and I don't understand "But how can they be saved fine in the temp variable and then get extra data in the vector when it's initialized with the same datatype?" Could you rephrase the question?

Comment: See my comment on the answer below. English is not my first language either so that might be why it's unclear ;) But I was wondering about the character after the L in 813 L " part, I was thinking that the actual data was the whole thing, and not that it first displayed the int and then the character.

Comment: @Seth: `wchar_t` is defined as neither `unsigned short` nor two bytes. There are pretty much no such concrete requirements on it at all, actually (`3.9.1/5`); it merely has to be able to support the largest extended character set amongst all available locales.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: Actually, they are on Windows, which is what this question is about.

Comment: @jpalecek: [So it would seem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367308%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). At the very least, then, Seth's original comment should really have a disclaimer on that it's only Windows that adds such a constraint; C++'s `wchar_t` _itself_ does _not_ hold that definition.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal sorry, I'm bad about remembering that linux exists too when I comment on questions where Windows is mentioned. (As an aside, that very page is where I got my info from too.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it is working fine. Microsoft just wants to facilitate inspecting `wchar_t` values (which are `short int`s and represent utf16 coded characters on windows), so their debugger shows `short int`s as `wchar_t`s. It's just a matter of interpretation.

If you had used `char`s for your data, you would encounter the same phenomenon on almost any architecture.

Comment: Thanks. I might have some other issue then, as the vector doesn't fill as it should after a while. So I guess I have a data problem and should really check if the numbers are correct. It's just weird that it works fine on linux. But where are those extra characters after the int from? Random pieces from memory? EDIT: Never mind, I guess that part after the L is the character...? Should've thought of that before, thanks again!

Comment: `s/and represent/and can represent/` There is nothing magical about a datatype `T` that automatically manages the encoding of arrays `T[N]`

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned short x;
    unsigned short y;
    unsigned short z;
} vec3_t;
```

and used vec3_t instead of std::vector.

In Windows wchar_t is the same as unsigned short, while in Unix it's 4 bytes long, so you should create your own vector type to make your code portable.

Comment: In UNIX it's unspecified how long it is (though 4 bytes does tend to follow from the requirement on locales).

Answer (score 0):

Everything works fine, it's just that wchar_t is a synonym for unsigned short on your platform and so the debugger doesn't know what name to display there. Also there is no 'more information' inserted. It's again the MSVC debugger interprets the number as a wide-character.